# Based on keyword found in cell, write integer next to it (apple→1, pear→2, etc)

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have this CSV file showing daily sales of fruits:

```
apple
pear
banana
apple
apple
```

I have decided to establish codes for each fruit 1=apple, 2=pear, 3=banana, etc (about 20 codes).

I want a new column containing the code:

```
apple  | 1
pear   | 2
banana | 3
apple  | 1
apple  | 1
```

How to add this column with Calc?

Comment: You write libreoffice-calc and openoffice-calc as tags. Both are different programs and may work slightly differently. Which of the 2 are you using?

Comment: @LPChip: LibreOffice, but bonus if a solution also works in OpenOffice and Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that the term for what you want to do is called a Vlookup in Excel. I believe it is the same name in other spreadsheet programs. Knowing the right keyword makes solving problems so much easier.

Here is the [Vlookup Fucntion](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#VLOOKUP) in LibreOffice. It's the same name in other programs as well, but the syntax might be slightly different.

Comment: Cool it looks like what I want to do indeed :-)